# White block behind Icon

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I remove the block behind the search icon shown in the image, the block displays in mac and not windows, want to remove for mac
the code is in bootstrap designed:

```
                <div class="search-container">
                  <form action="/search" method="get">
                    <input class="search expandright" id="searchright" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
                    <label type="button" class="ms-3 bg-white searchbutton border border-0 bg-none" for="searchright"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass mt-1"></i></label>
                  </form>
                </div>
```

The css code:

```
@media screen 
          and (min-device-width: 100px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1400px) 
     and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
           .expandright {
        left: 49px;
           right: auto; /* Button width-1px */
      }

        .expandright:focus {
             padding: 0 0 0 16px;
          border: 2px solid #006400;
             border-radius:  10px;
            }
         .search-container {
             position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
           margin: 4px 2px;
            height: 50px;
             width: 50px;
          vertical-align: bottom;
           }

         .searchbutton {
             position: absolute;
                font-size: 22px;
            width: 100%;
           margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
              }

          .search:focus + .searchbutton {
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
              -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
                -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
           -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
             background-color: none;
              color: none;
            }

         .search {
               position: absolute;
              left: 49px;
                background-color: white;
             outline: none;
               border: none;
               padding: 0;
             width: 0;
               height: 100%;
              z-index: 10;
               transition-duration: 0.4s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
           -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
           -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
       }
      }
```

[image]
were expecting to look like this

How to remove the background behind the search icon ?